# return multiple data on catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was experimenting with the fetch API and I was trying to return a log on fetch error what I did was catch the error and log the err caught by the catch and it works perfectly but when I add more console.log on the catch block it will execute whether the fetch caught an error or not. Why is this happening? And how can I return data other than error on the catch block? My code will explain it a bit more. Thanks in advance.

```js
fetch('api', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data)
  })
.catch(err =>
  console.log('error', err), //prints error on error 
  console.log("this is test") //print regardless of error(prints everytime the program runs even without error)
);
```

Comment: `err => 1, f()` is `(err => 1), f()`, you are calling `.catch` with a `console.log` call as second argument, and that includes calling `console.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because arrow functions without curly brackets can only contain one statement, and the other console.log is executed and its return value is passed to the .catch. What you wrote is the same as :

```js
fetch('api', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data)
  )
.catch(function(err){ // first argument
    console.log('error', err)
  },
  console.log("this is test") //second argument
)
```

If you want it to execute *only* in the .catch, use this instead :

```js
fetch('api', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data)
  )
.catch(err => {
  console.log('error', err), //prints error on error 
  console.log("this is test") //prints only on error
  }
);
```